# How to pass the query string using hidden fields in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to pass the query string using hidden fields in vb.net...

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455575/passing-hidden-field-from-one-page-to-another-in-querystring

Comment: In order to get good answers, try to explain *what you want to achieve*. As the question stands now, it is very hard to give any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting the question correctly, you want to pass all Fields in the Form (Which are Hidden) as QueryString.

I would suggest change the form Method to GET instead of POST

```
<form method="get" action="yourpage.aspx"><input type="hidden" name="field1"/><input type="hidden" name="field2"/><input type="submit" value="Go"/></form>
```

If you post the above form the Browser Location will look like

/yourpage.aspx?field1=value1&field2=value2

Comment: I wanna use asp.net standard conreols to do that ...

Comment: Still you can just set Form method to Get.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you well...

do you want to use the query string in the javascript code and you want to store it in an hidden field from the server side code? Consider that depending on what/when/how/when you want to use it you probably have it already also client side. something like document.location or document.source in any javascript method, why to get it from the server side into an hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to explose the form data using GET?

Still if you want to do that,make sure you properly HTMLEncode all the querystring values before processing.